# Send messages to specific socket without socket.io in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'd like to send messages through a socket to specific clients but can't seem to figure out how to do it without socket.io. The reason I can't use socket.io is because I'm trying to connect to a flash client, and I've read in numerous threads here on stackoverflow that socket.io isn't meant to connect to a flash clent. I have working code that will connect a node socket server to a socket client created in flash (actionscript 3), but it broadcasts the info to everyone connected to the socket. What I thought was if there was some way to send info to specific socket ids then I'd be in business. I looked in the docs and didn't find any info on how to do this, but then again I couldn't find any documentation about specific socket ids in the docs either, yet using "socket.id" will give the id so I'm wondering if there is some undocumented way to do this.

And just FYI this is for a card game where each player connected just gets their cards sent to them. The game logic is taken care of server side and I have that working. Now I just need to get each player only the info they need. Thanks.

Darryl

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure you can use `Adobe® Flash® Socket` in conjunction with socket.io. When you look at the available [transports(browsers)](http://socket.io/#browser-support) you will notice that socket.io also supports `Adobe® Flash® Socket`. But to be honest I do not know the exact details about this, but I think you can learn them by studying [socket.io's specification page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec).

When looking at [socket.io's WIKI](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki) I also found there already is a library to use socket.io with `Adobe® Flash® Socket`. The library is called [FlashSocket.IO](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO) which I believe can help you although I don't know any flash myself.

`Adobe® Flash® Socket` is standard disabled in the latest socket.io branches, but you can enable them easily by [studying configuring socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO). This page tells you how to enable all tranports which I will summarize below:

```
io.set('transports', [                     // enable all transports (optional if you want flashsocket)
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

If you have not yet had suffice answer(I think this should help you) I think you could also [file an issue at socket.io's issue page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues), because I find the socket.io's maintainers are super friendly and will tell you how to accomplish this without the least pain.

Finally to accomplish this using plain node you will have to keep track of all the active socket connections(sessions) yourself and only send that message to that specific socket. This is a mundane task, but I think there are more than enough tutorials available that teach you this(you could also look at socket.io how they achieve this, although this is a pretty large project/codebase).

I hope this answered your question. If not, I recommend you to ask a question in the comments for example.

Comment: Hey Alfred, thanks for the response. I actually looked at Flashsocket.io, but the issue I ran into is the same one with most tutorials: it isn't compatible with node 0.7.

As far as trying this with plain node I figured out the same as you about sending messages to specific socket connections, but I've looked at numerous node tutorials and haven't seen any the detail how to do that, at least none that don't use socket.io.

Where are the tutorials that you have seen that detail how to do send messages to a specific socket connection without socket.io?

Comment: @Darryl you can also install socket.io 0.6.x aside 0.7.x using npm. You can install packages locally using npm which will get installed in npm_module folder => http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/. Also there is a flashSocket.IO 0.7.x branch available => https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO/tree/0.7.x. Also a simple flash tutorial http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2011/05/22/tutorial-socket-server-with-flash-and-node-js/. You will have to some googling, but I had found better tutorials in the past.

Comment: Alfred, I'm reluctant to standardize on an obsolete version and I tried the 0.7 branch of flashsocket.io. Apparently it isn't complete (I talked to the author and he said he hadn't completely updated the files). I also couldn't find any examples of anyone using it for any more help. The flash tutorial at rhuno.com you posted is the one I have working. It doesn't have code to broadcast to a single client: the info is sent to every client connected using socket.write, a command which doesn't have a method to broadcast to a single client. And I've googled for about 3 weeks without success.